# How can I refresh the datatable's page automatically ?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jquery, datatable, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.4.

When I add a new data inside the database, I have to refresh the data table or the page to see the changes.

How can I make the page refreshing automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases add datatable id in the `update="datatableID"` attribute of the `p:ajax` or `p:commandButton`

Answer (score 0):

If you need the update be completely automatic and with no action from the user, like pushing a button, you need to use a poll

"Poll component make ajax calls in a specified interval."

```
<h:form id="form">  
<h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterBean.count}" />  

<p:poll interval="3"   
        listener="#{counterBean.increment}" update="txt_count" />  
</h:form>
```

this is the primefaces showcase sample
you can get ideas from it
cheers